# Including User's Id To Route

Tags: asp.net-core, razor-pages

When I log in as a user, my url for each one is /Identity/Account/Manage. I would like to add the id of the user to the url so I can have others click links to go to a specific user's profile.

**Index For User's Profile**

```
  @page "/Identity/Account/Manage/{id:int}"
@model IndexModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Profile";
    ViewData["ActivePage"] = ManageNavPages.Index;

}
```

**OnGetAsync**

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync()
    {
        var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User);
        if (user == null)
        {
            return NotFound($"Unable to load user with ID '{_userManager.GetUserId(User)}'.");
        }

        var userName = await _userManager.GetUserNameAsync(user);
        var email = await _userManager.GetEmailAsync(user);
        var phoneNumber = await _userManager.GetPhoneNumberAsync(user);


        Input = new InputModel
        {
            Email = email,
            PhoneNumber = phoneNumber,
            UserName = user.UserName,
            FirstName = user.FirstName,
            LastName = user.LastName,
            State = user.State,
            City = user.City,
            Image = user.Image,
            Reptile = user.Reptiles,
            Dog = user.Dogs,
            Cat = user.Cats
        };

        IsEmailConfirmed = await _userManager.IsEmailConfirmedAsync(user);

        return Page();
    }
```

Comment: Create a page with the route `@page "/Identity/Account/Manage/{id:guid}"` or string or whatever the type of that id is and then load the profile based on the supplied id.

Comment: Not sure how to load the profile based on the supplied id. Would I have to do it in the OnGetAsync Method? I will add my code.

Comment: Adding your code would be a first step, yes.

Comment: Sorry, about that. Code has been added.

Comment: If my answer is helpful,can you mark it as answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get Data from URL,you can use  `@RouteData.Values["xxx"]` in cshtml.cs.Here is a demo worked:

CreateBooking.cshtml:

```
@page "/Test/CreateBooking/{Id}"
```

CreateBooking.cshtml:

```
public ActionResult OnGet()
        {
            var id = @RouteData.Values["Id"];
            return Page();
        }
```

result:
[image]

Comment: Sorry about the late reply, was having a few problems with other parts of my code. Your answer is extremely helpful. My problem is I mixed razor pages (asp core) and traditional MVC (asp.net).